# Big union definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\bigcup A = \{x\;|\;(\exists b\in A)\;x\in b \}$$
I think $\exists b$ should be $\forall b$, otherwise $\bigcup A$ would have partial union of $A$. What is wrong with my thought?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a partial union, but a $\forall b$ would make this an intersection, i.e. the set of $x$ that belong to **all** sets in $A$.

Comment: To get better intuition about this, maybe try a small example. Say, let $A$ be a collection of 3 (small but nonempty) sets, and see what happens when computing $\bigcup A$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks, I got $\forall b$ leads to intersection. But what if there is just plain $b$ instead of $\exists b$? I can't still get why $\exists$ is needed.

Comment: The quantifier is needed to make it a well-formed expression. It's not clear what $(b \in A) \, x \in B$ means. It's not clear where $b$ comes from, or what it has to do with $x$ or $A$. Is $b$ a specific element of $A$ that only the author knows of? Is it something more general? Does it refer to all elements of $A$, or just some of them? This is where we need a quantifier to clarify things, as $(b \in A) \, x \in B$, by itself, doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well... What we want to express is that $\cup A$ is a collection of all the elements of all the sets $b$ in $A$.  But how would we express that mathematically? If we consider that $x \in \cup A \iff x\in$ some $b$ in $A\iff$ there is some $b \in A$ where $x \in b\iff (\exists b\in A)x\in b$.... The "all" $b\in A$ in the concept would intuitively mean "for all $b\in A$ we take all the elements of $B$ keep adding them to our 'big' set".  That's not really what $(\forall b\in A)x\in b$ is stating.

Comment: I suppose one could say $[(\forall b\in A)x\in b\implies x\in \cup A]\land [x\not\in \cup A\implies (\forall b\in A)x\not \in b]$ (in other words "for every set $b$ of $A$ all the elements of $b$ are in $\cup A$ and anything not in $\cup A$ cant be in any of the $b$ of $A$")  But that is not in set notation and it's not really a "definition" (it's an equivalent statement) as once you get out of the impluse to use "natural language" and thing in terms of absolute logical inference "$\cup A=\{x|(\exists b\in A)x\in b\}$ is more simple and direct.

Comment: @fleablood Really good explanation(examples) to me! Thanks it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\bigcup A = \{x\;|\;\exists b{\in}A\,\:x\in b \}\tag1$$

The RHS reads “the set of objects such that *each* lies in some element of $A$”.

(In other words, $x\in \bigcup A \iff \exists S{\in}A\,\:x\in S.)$

> $$\bigcup A = \{x\;|\;\forall b{\in}A\,\:x\in b \}\tag2$$

On the other hand, this new RHS reads “the set of objects such that *each* lies in every element of $A$”.

Thus, $(1)$ is correct while $(2)$ is wrong.